# Using gsutil in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to use gsutil in a firebase functions trigger? I would like to update variables containing multiples folders sizes each time a user add or delete a file in a storage bucket, so use `gsutil du -s gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[FOLDER_NAME]` in a storage trigger.

Also there is maybe an other solution to get buckets folders sizes than gsutil...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [@google-cloud/storage NPM module](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest) and specifically [Bucket.getFiles()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/Bucket#getFiles) to iterate through the list of files and add up their size. (I believe this is what `gsutil du` does under the hood). Note that if you have over 1,000 files returned you'll need handle paging the results.

Running the following function over HTTP you should get output like:

`3 files: 9.55MB / 10008960`

**index.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.bucketSizer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
  const bytes = require('bytes');
  const bucketName = 'MY_BUCKET_NAME';
  const dir = 'MY_DIRECTORY_NAME/';
  const options = {
    prefix: dir,
  };
  storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .getFiles(options)
    .then(results => {
      const files = results[0];
      let totalSize = 0;
      console.log('Files:');
      files.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file.name);
        let fileSize = parseInt(file.metadata.size);
        console.log(fileSize);
        totalSize += fileSize;
      });
      console.log("Total file size--> ", totalSize);
      res.send(`${files.length} files: ${bytes(totalSize)} / ${totalSize}`);
      return true;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});
```

**package.json**

```
$ npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
$ npm install --save bytes
```